# Google Freebase Api C# .Net Example

Tags: c#, json, google-api, freebase, mql

I am new to developing with the Goolge API’s. I am trying to get the Google.Apis.Freebase.V1 API working in C#. Does anyone have a small example on using this API in C#? I have spent the last several days looking and can only find a couple of examples for the old Freebase Api. Nothing for the Google API.

I am just looking for a simple example on setting up a connection to the API, doing a search, then how to handle a MQL query back into a Json object. The simpler the better.

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 3):

The correct code to do a MQL query in C# using the [Google API Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) should look something like this:

```
string API_KEY = "your-api-key-here";
FreebaseService service = new FreebaseService{ Key = API_KEY };
String query = "[{\"id\":null,\"name\":null,\"type\":\"/astronomy/planet\"}]";
FreebaseService.MqlreadRequest request = service.Mqlread(query);
string response = request.Fetch();
Console.WriteLine (response);
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be some sort of error with the client library right now as its not returning any results. I'll try to figure out what's going on there.

**Update:** The problem appears to be that the client library passes along an alt=json parameter which the Freebase API is unable to support. The Python client library has a way to disable this but there no way to do it in .Net. You can follow [the open bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=193) for this on the Google Code project.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. Please update when result issue is resolved.