# Google Freebase API .Net

Tags: c#, .net, freebase

I posted a request for a Freebase API C# .Net example a few months ago. But there appears to be a bug in the client library and I don’t see if being fixed in the near future.  You can see the original post here. [Google Freebase Api C# .Net Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991267/google-freebase-api-c-sharp-net-example)

And the bug report here. http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=193

My question is there another way to get a .Net service to connect and pull information from Freebase? If so can someone point me in the right direction, An example of some kind would really help. There is very little information out there on using the .Net  Google Freebase API.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: The previous question is actually at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991267/google-freebase-api-c-sharp-net-example

Comment: Thanks, not sure how that url got in there.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it simplier just to use `HttpWebRequest` and parse the answer as JSON?
I ended with choosing this option when I developed my app, and it took about several hours to write a liveable adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it solves your particular problem, but Microsoft recently released their own [Freebase API for .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2012/09/21/the-f-3-0-freebase-type-provider-sample-integrating-internet-scale-data-sources-into-a-strongly-typed-language.aspx) that you could try out. They also published a number of [usage samples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/tags/freebase+sample/). The folks at [FSharpx](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx) even wrapped it up into a [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/FSharpx.TypeProviders.Freebase).

Of course, you'll need to use F#, because C# and VB don't have the features this API is based on. But that's an added bonus when you consider how much nicer F# is.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at both options.

Answer (score 0):

I coped with the same problem. And decidd to write my own client as i did not see any good enough that could fit my requirements. You can get it here:
https://freebase4net.codeplex.com/
or 
Execute this line "Install-Package Freebase4net" in Package Manager Console

Code sample of usage:

```
var readService = FreebaseServices.CreateMqlReadService();

dynamic thepolice = new ExpandoObject();
thepolice.type = "/music/artist";
thepolice.name = FreebaseHelpers.Operators.CreateLikeOperator("^The Sco*$"); // Regex search
MqlReadServiceResponse result = await readService.ReadAsync(thepolice);
//Process result
var content = result.ResultAsString;
//get status
var status = result.Status;
```

More advanced samples of usage you can find here:
https://freebase4net.codeplex.com/documentation